# Shouldn't internal input resistance of a transistor be almost zero?

Tags: transistors, bjt, input-impedance

I am absolute beginner in electronics and the whole transistor thing is not looking very intuitive to me. Suppose this problem, in active region input terminal voltage almost remains constant with change in input current for a transistor. So, in terms of h-parameters, shouldn't \$h_i\$ (i.e. short circuit input impedance) be almost zero instead of a significant (typical 600-900 ohm) value?

Comment: Rin of bipolar is beta * 1/gm. With beta = 100, at 1ma (gm = 1/0.026, = 26 ohms, the Rin is 2,600 ohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, in terms of h-parameters, shouldn't \$h_{i}\$ be almost zero

Consider that the input to a BJT (in a common emitter configuration) is basically just driving a forward biased diode. Here's what a 1N4148 looks like just as an example. BJTs will be a little different in terms of collector voltage influences but well-within the same ball-park: -

[image]

So if you looked at the slope of the graph you could calculate dynamic input resistance versus forward voltage. At 0.8 volts the forward current is approximately 10 mA. At maybe 0.75 volts in, the current is about 8 mA. This means the dynamic input impedance is (0.8 - 0.75)/0.002 = 25 ohms.

At about 0.6 volts, the forward current is about 1 mA and if the voltage reduced to 0.55 volts, the current would be about 0.8 mA. Thus the dynamic resistance is now about 250 ohms.

Comment: Exactly. But unfortunately in my class and in lots of books that I have read ,they always stated to take forward voltage as 0.6-0.7 volts in active region as rule of thumb even when input current is far away from that corresponding to the forward voltage of 0.6-0.7 volts. I have to say their approximation is very rough.

Comment: @NewStudent in the bigger picture or the wider scheme of things, most BJT applications will use an emitter resistor and, when this happens, BJT base emitter dynamic impedance is relegated as an important factor so whether it’s 25 or 250 will be dwarfed by Re x beta projected at the base in series with the dynamic resistance.

Comment: @NewStudent, if the forward voltage stays the same, even when you change the base current (the model proposed by your books), that's the same as saying the input (differential) resistance is very small (the model you are proposing). So I don't see the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The resistance you're thinking of, called dynamic resistance or small signal resistance or differential resistance is the derivative \$dV/dI\$.

For a diode (which is what the base of a BJT looks like), \$V = kT/q \space\text{ln}(I/I_s)\$, so \$dV/dI = kT/q \cdot 1/I\$

kT/q is about 25 mV so if the base current is 10 microamps, dV/dI = 2500 ohms.